# Turtle, Reverse A List of Colors

Tags: python, colors, reverse

```
    import turtle as t
    import math

    #shape drawer function on turtle
    def drawer(a1, a2, b, ang, dist, clr): #a1 -> y-axis, a2 -> x-axis, b -> size of squares
        #define screen and drawer
        pen = t.Turtle()
        pen.shape("turtle")

        #define initial position
        pen.penup()
        pen.setposition(-(a2-0.5)*b, (a1-0.5)*b) #shape centered
        pen.pendown()

        for y in range(a1): #number of lines (y-axis)
             for x in range(a2): #number of squares on the same line (x-axis)
                 for s in range(4): #square shape
                    if y <= 6:
                        pen.color(colors[y%6]) #!!!!
                        pen.forward(b)
                        pen.right(90)
                    elif y > 6:
                        colors2 = colors[::-1] #!!!!
                        pen.color(colors2[(y-1)%6])
                        pen.forward(b)
                        pen.right(90)

                pen.penup()
                pen.forward(2*b)
                pen.pendown()

            pen.penup()
            pen.right(ang)
            pen.forward(dist)
            pen.left(ang)
            pen.pendown()

        t.done()

    #user-defined input
    n_line = int(input("Enter the number of lines of the shape:\n")) #y-axis
    n_sqr = int(input("Enter the number of squares in a line:\n")) #x-axis
    sqr = int(input("Enter the size of the squares:\n"))

    #trigonometric functions to adjust the shape on turtle
    n_ang = 180 - math.degrees(math.atan(1/n_sqr))
    n_dist = 1/(math.sin(math.radians(n_ang))/(2*sqr))

    colors = ["yellow", "orange", "red", "green", "blue", "purple"] #defined colors

    drawer(n_line, n_sqr, sqr, n_ang, n_dist, colors)
```

This is my code; making squares in turtle, each line with different colors.
I want to make square colors in order in the first 6 lines, then make colors of them in reversed order; 7th line blue, 8th line green, 9th line red, etc...Actually, my main idea was to create color wave:

- Line numbers 1-6 yellow to purple
- Line numbers 7-12 purple to yellow
- Line numbers 13-18 yellow to purple
- Line numbers 19-24 purple to
  yellow

etc...

I couldn't create the algorithm for this wave, any ideas ?
P.S. Please check #!!!! commented lines..

Comment: You really have a math question, not a programming question. You need to think of a function (rule) that translates the value of `y` into the desired index for `colors`. Or you could cheat by just making `colors` 12 elements long, duplicating the values in reverse order, so that you can just cycle through normally. :)

Comment: colors = ["yellow", "orange", "red", "green", "blue", "purple", "blue", "green", "red", "orange"]

and related field become:
pen.color(colors[y%10])
pen.forward(b)
pen.right(90)

that worked well! :D thx